# FilePond override server.process on React

Tags: reactjs, filepond

I'm trying to use the FilePond control in a React app. I need to handle file uploads with custom code. According to the documentation, I'm supposed to use setOption to override the server.process function. [Documentation Link](https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#advanced)

This doesn't appear to be an option when using a React component.

I can find multiple instances of people trying to do this, but can't find any examples of *how* it's done.

```
<FilePond 
  files={this.state.newFiles}
  allowMultiple={true}  
  server={this.someFunction}
/>
```

Comment: Did you checked this link? https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond

Comment: Yes, following those instructions adds ref={ref => (this.pond = ref)} and                      oninit={() => this.handleInit()} to the component. But, trying to call this.pond.setOptions fails with this.pond.setOptions is not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With React you need to use the `server` prop. The `server` prop is either a URL or a configuration object, not a function.

```
<FilePond 
  files={this.state.newFiles}
  allowMultiple={true}  
  server={{
    process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort, transfer, options) => {
        // your processing code here
    }
  }}
/>
```

For more information view this example processing function:
https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#advanced

Answer (score 0):

As stated in github issue [FilePond.SetOptions not worked](https://github.com/pqina/react-filepond/issues/40)

> With React the FilePond object is a component there is no global
>   FilePond object available at the moment. You can pass the server
>   properties to the component as a prop.

I believe you need to do the same, instead of calling `setOptions` function, you can pass these options as properties to `FilePond` component

If you really need to have access to `setOptions`, I have forked example from the react-filepond and added `useEfect` where you can see how to access `setOptions` function: [accees setOptions by ref](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-filepond-live-demo-egceh)

Comment: That sounds right...but how? I can add the property process={() =>this.uploadFiles()} but that never gets triggered.

Comment: Updated answer by adding an example how to get setOptions function, if this wont help could you please update your question with more details about what exactly you would like to achieve?